# Change the color of a graphic not drawn in a paint method

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, graphic

I have a JPanel that I want circles in to appear as I left click and for them to disappear when I right click.
I can make them appear on screen by drawing ellipses by getting the source from the mouse event click. 
However when I right click - to make them disappear I am just coloring the circle with the background colour of the JPanel and calling repaint().
This I know is wrong as the initial object wasn't drawn using the paint method.
Is there a way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you use clearRect() method ... ?

Comment: no - it isnt an avaliable method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the panel add `List<Shape>.` Override `paintComponent(Graphics g)`. Call super and then iterate through the list painting each `Shape`.

On click add a new `Ellipse` to the shapes list and call `repaint();`